# Navigation Controller is Hidden somewhere .. using swift

Tags: ios, swift, controller, navigation, storyboard

I have added many views in the storyboard and then one Navigation Controller. On each view I have added one action button. Segue action's checked.

At "Attributes Inspector" both "Shows Navigation Bar" and "Shows Toolbar" are set.

The buttons are visible on GUI, but they won't appear on simulator or device.

I didn't really see the point... but somebody over the web told me to write this piece of code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
}
```

My guess is that it should be visible unless said otherwise.

Any ideas about it? It should be simple and codeless.

For this test I just want to pop and purge views around the storyboard.

Thanks!
Best Regards,
Rick

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the storyboard?

Comment: Sure! From left to right: navigation controller, screen 1 (when user touches the first button the next screen is popped up on the stack), screen 2 (won't show the button "next"), screen 3 (won't show the button "check")... neither the "back" button is shown.

Comment: Here's the image: http://s9.postimg.org/6o23lhm73/screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you're getting the initial view controller from the storyboard by calling `initializeInitialViewController()` on the storyboard object, and as your storyboard shows, you don't have the navigation controller set to be the initial view controller.

Comment: Bullseye! The First ViewController was set as the initial viewe controller... and not the Navigation Controller! Thank you so much! Lesson learned!